# SQL Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, e-commerce

I'm reading a book about e-commerce. In this book I found the folowing SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `users_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `transaction_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `payment_status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `payment_amount` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `date_created` (`date_created` ASC),
    INDEX `transaction_id` (`transaction_id` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_users1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
        REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The book says that the CONSTRAINT would prevent the insertion of a "users_id" that doesn't match a 'id' in the table 'users'. By reading the code, I believe the book is wrong, because I believe this code would acctualy prevent the insertion of a "id" (in the table "orders") that doesn't match the field "id" (in the table users). I am right?

Sorry for bad english. I'm not american and trying my best...

Comment: The code should read `foreign key (user_id)` rather than `foreign key (id)`.

Comment: As a note:  you can contact the author or publisher who can make a correction in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `users_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `transaction_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `payment_status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `payment_amount` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `date_created` (`date_created` ASC),
    INDEX `transaction_id` (`transaction_id` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_users1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`)
        REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!